# Statistical tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Can someone please explain the difference between difference test and correlation test?

I am confused because e.g. if a mean of one group (males) is significantly different from the other (females), isn't there a correlation between this mean and its group at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

The word *correlate* is sometimes used informally as you use it, but in statistics it has a more formal definition.

If you measured height and weight in a bunch of kids of different ages, you'd find that on average the taller kids are also heavier. You could say then that height and weight are correlated.

If you measured height in men and women, you'd find that on average the men are taller. But a statistician wouldn't usually say that height correlates with gender. The concept is correct, but the term *correlate* is rarely used like that.

Comment: I find it helpful to try to draw the distinction between *association* (i.e.  knowing something about *X* tells you something about *Y*), and *correlation* which is an quantified measure of such association. Of course, different measures of correlation have different assumptions and properties built in.